# pgrouting OSM data with tolls

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

Is there any way to import the OSM data into pgRouting with the toll data?

I already have a database with OSM data with topology, and working with pgRouting, but I need to add some nodes to it.

I can see that in the `barrier=toll_booth` tag I can have the information that I need, and I can download this points from OSM separately.

The key is:

- Can I add this nodes to my current network,  in order to get it if my route crosses it?

Or if not,

- Can I re-download all the data with `osm2pgrouting` or `osm2po` including this nodes too?

Answer (score 1):

When you use osm2pgrouting to import OSM data, then you will find an attribute `osm_id` in your network table: https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting/wiki/Documentation-for-osm2pgrouting-v2.2#table-structure

There might be cases, where osm2pgrouting splits geometries during import, so `osm_id` isn't necessarly unique.
However, you can use `osm_id` to link to OSM data, that was imported using other tools.